# Getting a random toast when logging in

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hey this is very trivial problem but I am stuck on it from a while. 
Whenever I clear my app data and login into my app. I am getting a toast with text "asdad" Then when I switch my account or login with a different account I dont get this toast.

Tried searching everywhere in the project but didn't find the toast with the name "asdad" Even tried cleaning the project but didn't help. l̥Has someone faced this problem. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Toast does not comes up in any app default. You may have to search throughout your app to find the initiation and comment it out

Comment: provide your code..

Comment: he's right it didn't come up as default

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just follow this steps

> Edit > Find > Find in path > Text to find (type : asdad)

It will give you result

Comment: Thanks @Aditya Vyas